# Windows Defender reports Fuerboos.C!cl threat inconsistently

Tags: windows-10, malware, anti-virus, windows-defender, malware-detection

I'm not sure of the appropriate forum for this question since it kind of sits between programming and general computer use, but I'll try here because it has nothing to do with code yet.

I've been developing an Android (Xamarin) application, and I started getting reports from Windows Defender that it was detecting a severe threat called `Trojan:Win32/Fuerboos.C!cl` (described at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?Name=Trojan:Win32/Fuerboos.C!cl) on one of the very small pure Windows executables in my solution that I use for testing independently of the Android project.

I tried to narrow down the cause so I could post a more specific question with specific code, but just when I thought I had it (scanning a very small program was causing Windows Defender to report a threat), it stopped happening even after re-adding all the original code to my test program which was triggering the report earlier.

So it seems this "heuristic cloud protection rule" is triggered not just be the content of the file, but maybe some other context or operation related to the file.

How can I narrow down what is causing this file to be reported as a threat in order to get consistent results from Windows Defender?